# Deploy non-web Java application

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a relatively small Java app, which I'd like to move over to the Google App Engine. It runs in the console, with no user input needed after the initial startup. I researched a bit on how to deploy it, but all tutorials seem to focus on Java web apps, when I don't really need that. Is it possible to deploy my app if it's not a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine is probably the wrong GCP platform for you - you'd probably be better served just deploying your jar directly onto a Google Compute Engine node. GAE is pretty explicitly oriented around web applications and you'd need to do a bunch of configuration in order to have it work for your use case.

Comment: @DoNotSpamPls I hear ya. But that healthy free rate is oriented around a product with high scalability for _inbound web requests_ specifically. Anyways, if my answer's helpful please do mark it accepted :D

Answer (score 0):

Does your non-web Java app handle web requests? If not, it seems difficult to imagine that you would be able to reach your deployed app and use it for any purpose, once deployed. Your Java app should be able to handle requests, to make deployment worthwhile, and the deployed app useful.

You may find out about how your app should handle requests by reading the [How Requests are Handled](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/how-requests-are-handled) documentation page.